# Sums and products of binary relations

Tags: relations

Every function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is actually a relation between $X$ and $Y$:
$$R_f = \{ (x, f(x)) : x \in X \}$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are fields, we can take sums and products of two functions and say 
$$R_f + R_g = R_{f + g} = \{ (x, f(x) + g(x)) : x \in X\}$$
$$R_f * R_g = \{ (x, f(x) g(x)) : x \in X\}$$

But not every relation is a function, so it would be nice to add and multiply relations that are not functions. I suspect we can define the sum of two arbitrary relations between X and Y by
$$R + S = \{ (x, y_1 + y_2): (x, y_1) \in R, (x, y_2) \in S \}$$
and the product by 
$$R S = \{ (x, y_1 y_2): (x, y_1) \in R, (x, y_2) \in S \}.$$

Is this a good/correct definition? I assume this has been done before somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: can you explain what is $R$ and $S$ as subset and thinks

Comment: I'm taking R and S to be arbitrary relations, so each one could be any subset of X x Y.

Comment: in this case , the definition of R+S  and RS not complet, we must thinks at $(x_1,y_2)\in R$ and $(x_2,y_2)\in S $

Comment: I don't think that works, if I understand you correctly. Or at least, it doesn't satisfy $R_f + R_g = R_{f + g}$.

Comment: if you have laws  on $X$  and  on $Y$,  I think it's possible to induced  such laws in  the set of  relations from $X$ to $Y$ ( that is a subset of $X\times Y$)

Comment: he is not thinking about the intersection and to the meeting since
it is a set problem and not  algebraic problem, and then speaking
about compatibility   if in additional structure are of X and Y